# 2 DDNS 2 routers 2 web servers 1 issue

Tags: router, dynamic-dns

Please have patience and if you answer please explain like you would explain a moron.

This is my setup. I have 2 routers:

- Router 1 is [PPOE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol_over_Ethernet) and connected with a [NUC server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next_Unit_of_Computing) and [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) from [NoIP](https://www.noip.com/).
- Router 2 is connected to Router 1 with [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) and a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) webserver, as well as another DNS from NoIP.

When I connect wirelessly to Router 1 or 2, I can access `http://my address.com` from Raspberry Pi webserver (Router 2) without any problems. But when I connect over the web (like 4G), the connection is refused.

The Raspberry Pi also has a Dynamic DNS from NoIP. [DMZ](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)) is activated for NUC server on Router 1. If I stop DMZ on Router 1, I can no longer access the NUC webserver, which is connected to Router 1.

Now, my question is, why I can't access my Raspberry Pi webserver over the internet? I would also like to take this opportunity to thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Why I can't access my Raspberry Pi webserver over the internet?

At a guess, because you haven't set up the NUC web server to be a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) (i.e. to forward web requests, based on your Dynamic DNS domain for the Raspberry Pi, to your Raspberry Pi itself).

Typically, only one web server can be associated with an IP address at a time (independent of Dynamic DNS names). So when an external request (e.g. 4G) for ex. `mypi.noip.com` is received by your NUC, it likely simply drops it. You need to explicitly tell the NUC web server software to pass requests for ex. `mypi.noip.com` to the Raspberry Pi on your local network. The NUC would then return any messages from the Raspberry Pi (e.g. a web page) to any external client.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Anaksunaman. As I said I am a bit of a beginner and a moron . Can you explain to me how to get the NUC webserver to redirect a noip request to the raspberry pi. I need to mention that NUC and raspberry have installed WordPress websites. NUC  https:// mywebsite-1.com and raspberry http:/ my website.noip-2.com.

Comment: You're welcome . I may be able to give you some pointers but you would need to update (edit) your question to include the operating system for your NUC and (more importantly) the actual web server software that serves your WordPress sites (such as [Apache](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server), [Nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) or [some other web server software](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_server_software)). Support for using a web server as a reverse proxy and any other necessary or specific steps typically depend on these factors.